# Magento 2: Show subcategory titles & products in order?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm wondering if there's a default way of doing this. My category structure is as follows:

```
Root
    Category 1
              Sub 1
                   Product 1
                   Product 2
              Sub 2
                   Product 3
                   Product 4
```

I need to display the two sub categories (Sub 1, Sub 2) on the parent category (Category 1) with the names of the sub categories and the relevant products below the titles. A rough design is as follows:

---

Page URL: www.domain.co.uk/category-1

**Sub 1**

- Product 1
- Product 2

**Sub 2**

- Product 3
- Product 4

---

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this? I've been making changes to Magento_Catalog/product/list.phtml and have managed to pull the sub categories however I'm struggling on getting the products to sit under the titles.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How are you going to work with pagination or sorting? Will all products display on one page?

Comment: @Konstantin I've added the way I've done it below, good ol' widgets!

Answer (score 0):

I just remembered I can use static blocks and widgets to pull category products! Leaving this question here incase anyone else needs advice on how to pull subcategories with titles (you can add titles via the widget customiser).